# Problem with Draftsight activation

Tags: cad

I have installed DraftSight recently and every time it requires entering my email for activation , I tried to remove it and deleted it's configuration files with this 
rm -Rv ~/.config/DraftSight 
then reinstalled it but the same problems occurs 
can you help me please ? I need it badly as it's the only good autocad clone out there I tried Librecad but I was disappointed

Comment: Did you activate the the email you entered when installing it, as I did and I don't get asked the email on new launches?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what do you mean by activating the email ?
I entered a valid email address but i didn't get any message for activation link , the program opens but after closing and opening it again it asks again for activation

Comment: That's because you need to activate it from the email you entered you should have gotten a link to click to activate. Is your version free for non-commercial use?

Comment: thanks for your answer but I didn't get any links in my email
it's the free one

Comment: You should have please do it again and check your spam box!

Comment: You might find [this](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/84937) useful.

Answer (score 1):

I might found a solution. 
There was a message about IBUS during the instalation. The owner is not root. Somewhere here I found that it could load gksudo. So, in directory `/usr/share/applications` find DraftSight and paste to terminal `gksudo /COPIED_DIRECTORY`.

Again fill in email and other info. Open your email inbox and click the link. (DraftSight site will load). Start again command with `gksudo` and DraftSight will load.

I know that it isn't a complete solution just small way around, but it's running!

Comment: didn't work with me
 but thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with their servers (and it's obviously not a high priority for Dassault as I learned from reading loads of posts on various forums, it's a long-time one).
If you don't receive the activation e-mail almost instantly, just keep trying.
I know this is probably not the answer you hoped for but AFAIK it's the only thing that works now as the problem is on their side, tested on several installations).

Answer (score 0):

During the install:

`chmod 777 /usr/share/applications/dassault-systemes_draftsight.desktop`

...Open your email inbox and click the link,

and after the first launch:

`chmod 644 /usr/share/applications/dassault-systemes_draftsight.desktop`

It's OK, on debian stretch.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer 

I have tried  to run it in terminal with sudo command  and it gave me this error 

Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x324cea0 ??

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

First remove draftsight and any left over configurations

```
sudo apt purge draftsight
rm -rf ~/.config/DraftSight
rm -rf ~/.config/SWActivation
```

Next start a login shell as root and install the deb

```
sudo su
dpkg -i draftSight.deb
```

Exit the shell and run draft sight as normal user from your applications menu.    After that, when you input the activation information you should get a dialog saying the activation request has been sent and to check your email. I think the deb install has a problem if you install it with sudo instead of a full root login shell which is why you see the ibus error.

Comment: thank you very much for your response 

I have tried this and I tried to run it in terminal and it gave me this error 

Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x324cea0 ??